# Losing Set-Cookie in Response Header on one server in multi server Windows IIS .NET environment

Tags: asp.net, iis, cookies, load-balancing, iis-10

We have a somewhat odd situation.

Our environment consists of 2 web servers (Windows 2016 running IIS) and a load balancer. The applications are running .Net Framework 4.

MachineKey with matching Encrypt/Decrypt and other attributes exists in the .Net web.config (server level).

We noticed that the Set-Cookie Response header was missing when making requests to a specific server.

Further digging identified the following.

Direct URL request following authentication to Server 2 - Response Set-Cookie with Auth cookie correctly set.

Refresh of the URL on Server 2, Request Cookie sent with Auth cookie, Response Set-Cookie with Auth cookie correctly set again, new cookie with sliding expiration date.

Request of the same URL on Server 1, Request Cookie sent with Auth cookie (cookie is HTTP Only but allows any server in the domain to access), Single Sign On Auth is successful since MachineKeys match, Response Set-Cookie with Auth cookie correctly set again, new cookie with sliding expiration date.

Request of the same URL back on Server 2, Request Cookie is sent, user is still authenticated ask cookie is still valid, but no Response Set-Cookie comes back with the server Response.

From that point forward no Set-Cookie will come back from Server 2 until a logout is forced, which returns a Response Set-Cookie with expiration date set in the past, which browser sees and expires the cookie.

IP Stickiness cannot be enabled on the Load Balancer (due to CDN and other restrictions), so a user that authenticates on Server 1, or accesses Server 1 for any requests, results in no longer receiving any Response Set-Cookie headers from Server 2.

Application is proven and has worked correctly in several similar environments. Seems to be server specific issue.

Any ideas on server configuration that may cause this?